# Is it possible to force zsh parameter expansion earlier?

Tags: zsh

Problem: I currently have in my zsh-script a pipe of this structure

```
a|b|c|d|e >result
```

I would like to modify this, so that if some variable $v is not empty, the file `result` should contain only those lines which match the regexp in $v. Here are three obvious ways to do it:

```
# I don't like this because it causes an extra (possibly large)
# temporary file
a|b|c|d|e >result
if [[ -n $v ]]
then
  mv result result1
  grep -E $v result1 >result
  rm result1
fi
```

or

```
# I don't like this, because I have to repeat the pipe,
# which makes it error-prone to maintain.
if [[ -z $v ]]
then
  a|b|c|d|e >result
else
  a|b|c|d|e|grep -F $v >result
fi
```

Or:

```
# I don't like this, because in practice, $v will be empty most
# of the time, and I then have an unnecessary additional process 
# in the pipeline
if [[ -z $v ]]
then
  filter=cat
else
  filter='grep -E $v'
fi
a|b|c|d|e|${(z)filter} >result
```

What I really would like to have is something like:

```
# This does not work
if [[ -z $v ]]
then
  filter=
else
  filter='|grep -E $v'
fi
a|b|c|d|e ${(z)filter} >result
```

This does not work, because Zsh first identifies the individual commands and THEN evaluates the parameters and therefore passes my filter command as parameter to program *e*.

I am aware that I could also solve this by building my command line based on the value of $v and then use `eval`, but I don't like this either, because in the actual case, all the programs involved get several parameters with a lot of quoting going on, and putting this in a form which still works when being eval'ed can also easily lead to errors.

Is there a different way to force the evaluation of $filter being done before the commands are built? I'm using Zsh 5.3.

Comment: sometimes `grep -E` and sometimes `grep -F` is it a typo, there's also another solution but runs grep always : `grep -E "${v:-^}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pipe *into* the `if` statement. You can duplicate `e`:

```
a | b | c | d | e |
  if [[ -z $v ]]; then
    e
  else
    e | grep -F $v
  fi > result
```

or, at the expense of an extra `cat` command to pass the output through the pipe, pull `e` out of the `if`:

```
a | b | c | d | e |
  if [[ -z $v ]]; then
    cat
  else
    grep -F $v
  fi > result
```

Or you could use parameter expansion to define an "accept anything" pattern to use with `grep`.

```
a | b | c | d | e | grep -F ${v:-.} > result
```

Answer (score 0):

a solution may be to use fifo and file descriptors, something like

```
# open fd 3
if [[ -z $v ]]; then
    exec 3> result
else
    fifo=/tmp/fifo$$
    mkfifo "$fifo"
    grep -E "$v" "$fifo" >result & grep_pid=$!
    exec 3>"$fifo"
end

a|b|c|d|e >&3

# close fd3 and clean
exec 3>&-
if [[ -n $v ]]; then
    wait $grep_pid
    rm "$fifo"
fi
```